# 404 error page when trying to access website (hostgator)

Tags: web-hosting

I have recently finished building my website and since I didn't know how to put it online I decided to follow this tutorial: https://youtu.be/tq7dqdHCc7U
Everything worked fine until I tried to upload my .html files. I copied them into a www folder I created, but when I try to access the site with myIP/~username, I get a 404 error page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have put html file in wrong directory. Please put a sample index.html in root directory and in public_html folder. and try to access with domain name. it should work

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error means that a valid page wasn't found. The only html file that apache know to render automatically is an index.html file. That's the default for the root url (in your case: yourIP/~username). So to fix the problem, you can either change what apache looks for in a index page in your httpd.conf, rename one of your files to index.html, or just append the name of a file that *does* exist to the end of your URL: `yourIP/~username/myPage.html`

Comment: That didn't work. When I try to access my website with my domain name instead of my IP and username, a "getting started" page by hostgator shows up. Someone in the comments of the video tutorial said something about having to change the nameserver with godaddy, but I'm not sure why you would have to do that.

Comment: Your computer resolves a named url to the IP address of your server by asking a nameserver. If you very recently purchased the domain, it can take up to a few hours for your domain to propagate through the various DNS servers and actually be correctly resolved. But using the exact IP of your server should circumvent that problem. I haven't used hostgator in particular, but I have purchased domains elsewhere, and I have experience setting up apache servers so I'll do my best to help you. I'll need more info about your setup, so you purchased a domain and web hosting plan from hostgator?

Comment: After re-reading your original post, I saw that you created the www folder yourself? It should be created automatically by apache, so you must have put your files in the wrong directory. Look in the /var/www/html or /var/www directories

Comment: I didn't find an www folder, but it worked with the public_html folder after renaming my index file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This IP based url does not work w/ my client's hatchling hostgator account even though this url method is still shown in hostgator's documentation. Instead you must use the cpanel's temporary url and it must be http not be htttps.